# Google Place API city search by coordinates

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, google-places-api

I'm trying to access cities from the google place API. I want to be able to search with coordinates and have it return a city. My goal is for a user to be able to enter in a city and a photo shows up. So after getting the city, I will use the photo reference to get the image.

This is my request

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=35.4107,80.8429&radius=100&sensor=true&key=API_KEY

the coordinates entered is a City in North Carolina. However, it does not return a city within North Carolina at all. All I am looking to do is use coordinates inside my request and have it return the city the coordinates are in. I'm relatively new to development, if I have been unclear in any way please point it out so that I may correct myself. Thanks!

Comment: U mean its showing result but not near results right?

Comment: @krishnar it shows limited results. The results that it does show are for somewhere called “Hoton”

Comment: Did u tried where these coords showing in GoogleMaps?

Comment: Yes. If I enter the coordinates directly into the browser it will pull up the city on google. But when I go through the google place api it’s not outputting the city I’m looking for.

Comment: You have a typo in your coordinates.  North Carolina is at -80 degrees longitude.  China is at 80 degrees longitude.

Comment: Thanks @ geocodezip. Google maps listed it as "35.4107° N, 80.8429° W" I must have gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) is more suitable for your task than Places API. Places API is designed to search businesses and POIs at first place, localities shouldn't be among the results.

With reverse geocoding you can specify a coordinate and type of result you are looking for. For example, to search the city use the following request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.4107%2C-80.8429&result_type=locality&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

This will return the "Huntersville, NC 28078, USA"

[image]